# Android Drawable Importer Error - "You have to select the Android Icons asset folder in the settings"

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-drawable-importer

I have download the [Action Bar Icon Pack](https://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html#action-bar-icon-pack) and now I want to import some icons the `res` directory. I was able to simple copy and paste the folders for one image, but this works only for the first time:

[image]

Now, I have images in the following structure and want to put each one to the corresponding `res` sub-folder:

- 02_navigation_back

  - drawable-hdpi

    - ic_action_back.png
  - drawable-mdpi

    - ic_action_back.png
  - drawable-xhdpi

    - ic_action_back.png
  - drawable-xxhdpi

    - ic_action_back.png

I have installed the [Android Draw-able Importer](https://github.com/winterDroid/android-drawable-importer-intellij-plugin) in order not to do this by hand. But when I try to use the `AndroidIcons Drawable Import` or `Material Icons Drawable Import` options I am getting the following error:

> You have to select the Android Icons asset folder in the settings!

The `Scaled Drawable` option seems to work, but it `accepts` only one image and create the rest automatically I think.

How to import the icons from the pack and put each image in the correct folder automatically?

I am using `Android Studio` 1.2 Beta 3 under `Ubuntu 15.04`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose I have understand what was wrong. I need to specify the `root` folders where icons for `AndroidIcons Drawable Import` and `Material Icons Drawable Import` options are stored.

And the above is the in the following menu, but note that the plug-in is expecting a specific folder structure (structure that is not the same as the one of the `Action Bar Icon Pack`:

[image]

So, I have instead use the `Download` options to download the `Androidicons` and `Material icons` pack instead. I set their root folders paths in the settings and I am now able to use their icons:

[image]

In order to use icons from the `Action Bar Icon Pack` I need to use the `Android Multi Drawable Importer` which is not as fast as I wanted it to be.

So, I guess the only options is to put the icons I wanted to use from the `Action Bar Icon Pack` to the `Android Drawable Importer` folder structure.

[image]